# Linking android game to facebook friends who also play

Tags: android, google-app-engine, facebook-graph-api, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to create a card game for the Android platform, which will be played over the network, one turn at a time. I am hoping to use Google App Engine for my server backend, and Google Cloud Messaging to notify players when it's their turn. My idea approach this implementation is to have users login through the Facebook APIs, store the facebook user id and then register the app with Google Cloud Messaging and store the Registration ID. Then both the facebook and GCM ids would be submitted to the server and stored in the GAE datastore. To generate a list of friends to start a new game with, would I just use the facebook Open Graph API to get a list of the user's friends' ids and then compare each of the facebook ids stored on the server to the list of facebook friends? Or is there a better way to get a list of facebook friends who also have the app installed?

After each turn, the android app would serialize a "game" object and upload it to the GAE, which would then use the saved Registration id to notify the other player(s). When the app opens on a device, it would download the serialized "game" object(s) pending on the server, and inflate it and proceed with the next turn. This is my first attempt at programming anything more complicated than a simple website with a little JavaScript. Any help or direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Or is there a better way to get a list of facebook friends who also have the app installed?

FQL query on the `user` table, selecting all users whose uid is connected to your current user’s id in the `friend` table, and has `is_app_user` set to true.

Comment: Thanks, this looks to be pretty easy to implement. The Graph API also supports HTTP request for a JSON Object containing the user's friends and their ids (and pictures,names, etc.), and can contain an "installed" field if field=installed is added to the URL (eg. facebook.com/CURRENT_USER_ID/friends?access_token=...&fields=installed, name, picture). You can then call the android methods for working with JSON objects. There seems to be more information on the Graph API than FQL?

Comment: Yes, but the Graph API does not support filtering by `installed` as far as I know – so you would (have to) get all friends of a user, and filter only those that have your app installed afterwards yourself. You can also send an FQL query to the Graph API endpoint, `/fql?q=query` – _“There seems to be more information on the Graph API than FQL?”_ – what do you mean, more of the user information you want to query, or more information on the subjects in the documentation? If the latter is the problem, don’t worry, I can tell you the exact FQL query if you can’t get it set up yourself ;-)

Comment: Thanks CBroe, apparently missed a large portion of the facebook documentation for the android SDK so wasn't finding much documentation for FQL, but lots of information @ http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/androidsdk/ . Looks like the Graph API does support installed (referenced against the access_token in the graphPath param of the .request(String graphPath) i.e. "me/friends?access_token...&fields=installed, id, name, picture" , which returns a JSON string with the requested information, so you could populate a View with a list of the user's friends names, with pictures,

Comment: with the game installed. If you store the facebook user id for each user in a database (or DataStore for GAE) on the server along with the equivalent id for Google Cloud Messager when the user first signs in, when a user completes a turn you could query the server DB for the facebook and GCM ID of the other player, and use the GCM ID to send a notification to the other player. Of course, this could be accomplished with a FQL query as well, I just seem to be more comfortable with the Graph API, and the Documentation was easier for me to follow:) I may ask for FQL help in the future if thats ok!

Comment: UPDATE: Turns out you CAN query for friends with the app installed. The path is "me/friends" and the bundle parameters are "field":"installed". It will return a list of ALL friends, and those with the app authorized will have a field "installed=true", which you can pull from the returned JSON data.